# ClickHouse - Merge similar entries into a new one

Tags: duplicates, clickhouse

This is my current (simplified) model in ClickHouse:

### Credential table

- user: String
- domain: String
- password: String
- leak: UInt64

The field `leak` is a reference to the id of a leak.

### Leak table

- id: UInt64
- name: String
- desc: String
- date: String

I'm using the MergeTree engine for `Credential` and Log for `Leak`.
Sometimes, two sames credentials are inserted, so I have for example:
**| user | domain | password | 0 |**
**| user | domain | password | 1 |**

I would like to turn this into:
**| user | domain | password | [0, 1] |**

I've read about ReplacingMergeTree but I did not find another way to specify some rules of rewriting/deleting than the `version` parameter.

My problem is I have billions of entries and it sounds crazy to process the data before insertion. Even if ClickHouse's response times are incredibly low, it seems ridiculous to check if every new credential I'm trying to insert is already in there, and if it is, update its data, right ?

I'm trying to reduce disk storage as much as possible, but it looks hard to balance it with keeping these incredible response times. I'm listening to your ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of ways to deal with this.

1. You can create a `Materialized Table` along with your actual table.
2. You can use `ReplacingMergeTree`.
3. You can mutate(ALTER UPDATE) existing data.
4. Use your table as is but query it using `groupArray` to get the result you want.

Here I demonstrate 4th solution. You just insert your data in `MergeTree` as you always do. But when you query it, you use `groupArray` to roll the desired column to be an array based on other columns.

Let's say your table is something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mem

┌─a─────┬─b───────┬─c─────────┬─d─┐
│ user1 │ domain1 │ password1 │ 0 │
│ user1 │ domain1 │ password1 │ 1 │
│ user2 │ domain2 │ password2 │ 0 │
│ user2 │ domain2 │ password2 │ 2 │
└───────┴─────────┴───────────┴───┘
```

You use `groupArray` to solve your problem:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, groupArray(d)
FROM mem
GROUP BY a, b, c

┌─a─────┬─b───────┬─c─────────┬─groupArray(d)─┐
│ user2 │ domain2 │ password2 │ [0,2]         │
│ user1 │ domain1 │ password1 │ [0,1]         │
└───────┴─────────┴───────────┴───────────────┘
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of the table definition and an insert example to make sure I understand it well? Because it seems to me data is still stored twice instead of once

Comment: @Chocorean, yes, data is still stored in multiple rows. If you want only one row, you can use `ReplacingMergeTree`.

Comment: It does not solve by issue. CLickHouse does not have a native solution for this, I would have need a kind of custom "replacing rule". But nvm, I'm currently checking for existence before inserting.

Comment: @Chocorean Actually Clickhouse has a native solution for this it is called `AggregatingMergeTree`. The problem is, your data type is array and I couldn't make it aggregate columns as array in `AggregatingMergeTree`. Working on it.

Comment: Yeah right, my problem is I cannot specify a rule to apply each time the engine is aggregating data... Would be great to see this kind of feature !